# Feature Request EOL Tags

Tags: feature-request

## Feature Request for Tags

Some of the tags used on DBA.SE (and possibly other sites) are related to a specific version of a product or exist as part of a certain product. It would be nice to have a feature in the tags that would allow the community to mark a tag as obsolete, no longer required or EOL.

### Reasons for Marking a Tag

Reasons for marking a tag could be:

- End-Of-Life (EOL)
- Deprecated (no longer used)
- No longer available
- other reasons?

Users would mark a tag via a check-box in the tag section of a site and be able to select from the above list of reasons.

### Tag Handling

The tag would end up in the queue where community members with a score of 5000 reputation could vote to "soft-close" the tag.

### Soft Closed Tags

Soft-closed tags would appear as greyed out or marked with a certain colour (orange?) to discern them from regular tags. When a user selects a soft-closed tag for a question a warning pops up à la:

> **Caution**
> The tag your are selecting is no longer supported.
> The product / software / hardware is no longer available and should be upgraded/replaced.

## Benefits for The Community

Soft-closed tags are visible and allow the community to discern between relevant information and possibly no longer relevant information.

## Open for Suggestions

This feature request is open for additional suggestions of how we could handle "old" tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I lean towards simply editing the tag wiki to include the deprecation date and/or the date the product became unsupported.

Most, if not all, subject matter experts know that specific products or product-versions are no longer supported, and hence don't really need to know *from the color of a tag* that the product is "old".

Furthermore, for old questions, all the tags might easily be "orange", reducing the opportunity for someone to provide a helpful answer.  Admittedly, the older a product is, the less useful an answer will be to future visitors, but that's generally the case for *all* old questions at some point in time.

I just don't really see the benefit, personally.  If someone comes here with a question about some old version, they probably actually need help, not to be shunned by the community because their question is about some old, tired, un-cool product.

Comment: Agreed. This seems like the wrong solution to a different problem. If there really is content of no use to anyone at all, it should be reviewed for deletion. There are a lot of things wrong with tags, but this isn't one of those things.